# I want to store changeable data within one column of my table row

Tags: javascript, mysql, laravel, vuejs2, mariadb

So, I have a vue component called stats. Basically how its stored is it has a name for example: 'goals'. It fetches the row with the id/name of 'goals' from the database and the point is to access the info column within that to fetch specific data.

This is how the row would look

```sql
ID   Name    Info                         Created_at               Updated_at
"1" "user"  "{"goal": 1,"current":500}" "2019-04-28 03:54:44"   "2019-04-28 03:54:46"
```

I want to be able to access the data within the Info column and display it accordingly. I can't seem how to get it working though within javascript.

This is how i call it

```js
 axios.get('/api/stats/user').then((res) => {this.test = res.data; console.log(this.test)});
```

and in the console i get the object i want but info looks like this:

```js
info: "{"goal": 1000, "current":500}"
```

and I can't seem to be able to grab it by ['goal'] or this.test.info.goal which is what I want

Comment: info field json ?

Comment: @AhmedAboud Thats the idea, i was going to use JSON.stringify() when adding it to the database

Comment: check this out https://laraveldaily.com/working-with-mysql-json-columns-in-laravel-custom-properties-example/

Comment: If every row has `goal` and `current`, then it is counterproductive to use `JSON` for them.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create a [resource](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources) file for yor model and create an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) for your info/goal field.
You should use the resource files for each json response which contains models/collection of models.
This way you can modify what to display in your json response about each model.